# Sum of Binomial Coefficient with N changing exponentially and Fixed K

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

Hello Mathematical Community,
  I need your help.I want to calculate sum of Binomial Coefficients where N is varying and K is fixed.

What I need to calculate is the below function :-`
$$
f(n) = \sum_{i=0}^n {a^i \choose  k}
$$

for eg- if N = 4, a = 3, and k = 2
I need to calculate

$ ~^{3^0}C_2 + ^{3^1}C_2 + ^{3^2}C_2+ ^{3^3}C_2+ ^{3^4}C_2  =  ~^{1}C_2 + ^{3}C_2 + ^{9}C_2+ ^{27}C_2+ ^{81}C_2~$

Points to Note -

1. N is rising exponentially
2. K is fixed
3. Need to calculate the sum for a particular value of N, a and k as listed in the expression above.

I have read so much about the Binomial Coefficient but couldn't find any formula or pattern from which I can derive a relation.

Any help would be nice. Thank you guys for keeping mathematicians motivated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. What is $N$ ? is $N=n$ or $N=a^i$. If the former, then why do you sqy that it is rising exponenitally, if the latter then in your example it's not $N=4$ but $n=4$.

Comment: When you say "Need to calculate the sum for a particular value of N, a and k as listed in the expression above", do you mean "any value", or is it indeed specific values, and if so which ones?